# which salesforce edition to be used and what is the pricing?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

what is the pricing and which is the edition to be used for custom application developement.dont want to have standard objects and standard apps.
Require
1.worflow and approval process.
2.email capability
3.report and dashboard
4 apex and visualforce

Answer (score 1):

http://www.salesforce.com/uk/crm/editions-pricing.jsp has an overview of the various SalesForce offerings including list pricing. It also links to http://www.sfdcstatic.com/uk/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf which has a more detailed breakdown of what is included in each offering.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you need either Enterprise edition or Performace edition
[[https://secure2.sfdcstatic.com/eu/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf][1]](https://secure2.sfdcstatic.com/eu/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf%5d%5b1%5d)